# How to return rows from multiple tables with a Postrgresql function

Tags: postgresql, functions

This is the selection I want to make:

```
select figurita.codigo,figurita.imagen, jugadores.nombre, jugadores.apellidos, jugadores.numero,jugadores.peso,jugadores.altura,jugadores.fechanac,
posiciones.nombre as posicion,paises.nombre as pais ,selecciones.codigofifa, grupos.nombre as grupo
from figurita 
inner join jugadores  on jugadores.id=figurita.jugadorid
inner join posiciones on posiciones.id= jugadores.posicionid
inner join selecciones on selecciones.id=jugadores.seleccionid
inner join paises on paises.id=selecciones.paisid
inner join grupos on grupos.id=selecciones.grupoid
where figurita.codigo='AAA-005';
```

And this is the function I'm trying to do:

```
create or replace function get_figura5(codigo_input varchar)returns 
table (codigo varchar,imagen varchar,nombre varchar, apellidos varchar, numero int,peso int, altura int, fechanac date, posicion varchar, pais varchar, codigofifa varchar, grupo varchar)

as $$ 
begin
  select figurita.codigo,figurita.imagen, jugadores.nombre, jugadores.apellidos, jugadores.numero,jugadores.peso,jugadores.altura,jugadores.fechanac,
  posiciones.nombre as posicion,paises.nombre as pais ,selecciones.codigofifa, grupos.nombre as grupo
  from figurita 
  inner join jugadores  on jugadores.id=figurita.jugadorid
  inner join posiciones on posiciones.id= jugadores.posicionid
  inner join selecciones on selecciones.id=jugadores.seleccionid
  inner join paises on paises.id=selecciones.paisid
  inner join grupos on grupos.id=selecciones.grupoid
  where figurita.codigo=codigo_input;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

and when I execute the procedure I get this error, I understand that the problem is in the return but I do not know what kind of data to put there

```
select * from get_figura5('AAA-001');
```

returns error message

```
Failed to run sql query: query has no destination for result data
```

Answer (score 1):

Either:

- Mark your function `language sql`, or
- Add `RETURN` before `SELECT` to return the output of the query.

In PL/pgSQL, the output of `SELECT` must go somewhere (usually a variable). In SQL, it’s implied the output is returned.